# Google drive api scope

Tags: php, api, google-api

This is my code

```
<?php

    require_once     '/home/bachus03/domains/bachus03.vot.pl/public_html/fb/vendor/autoload.php';

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/bachus03/domains/bachus03.vot.pl/public_html/fb/public/service-account.json');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata']);
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

    $files = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);
    $response = $files->getOwners();
    echo json_encode($response) . "\n";

?>
```

And after I run my test.php script I get:

```
[bachus03@s14:: ~ ]:$    /usr/local/php/p56/bin/php   /home/bachus03/domains/bachus03.vot.pl/public_html/fb/public/test.php
NUll
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You downloaded [that extension class](https://api.kdyby.org/class-Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile.html), right? Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Yes, and I have erros on. I just want to make a connection wich will work" behind the scenes i dont't want to user have to log in. i vat list files on goole drive...